# PHP code to echo exploded values inside textbox from database

Tags: php, sql

I have a textbox.

Data in my table are as follow:

```
col1     col2
701       500
701       501
701       503
```

I need to display all `col2` value in single textbox on edit button click like below:

```
500, 501, 502
```

Can you please help me to display all `col2` values in textbox from the database?

Here is my code for that:

```
<?php  
  $data = 0;
  if(isset($_GET['edit']))
  {
  $col1= $_GET['edit'];
  $data = $database->getRow("SELECT * FROM master where col1= :col1",array(':col1'=>$col1));  
  }     
?>
```

I have tried this but this shows an array inside textbox....

```
<input type="text" name="col2"  value="<?php echo explode(',', $data['col2']); ?>"/>
```

Comment: when u explode something, it will return array, so u can use foreach loop to loop through that array and echo it in input box's value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
  {
    $col1= $_GET['edit'];
    $query = Mysqli_Query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM `master` WHERE `col1`='$col1'") or die(mysql_error());

    if( ! mysqli_num_rows($query) ) 
      {
      echo 'No results found';
      }
      else
      {
     echo '<input type="text" name="col2"  value="';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {    
      echo $row['col2'].', ';
      }
    echo '"/>';
}
```

By the way, simply $_GET'ing the value is unsafe and leads to XSS vulnerability.

Comment: i need with pdo and i want output im my format...bcoz there are 35 col in my table....thats why i prefer this way....plz help with this...

Comment: I'm not good in PDO, so I wont be able to assist you with that, but you will still need the while cycle, like I provided. Only the declaration will be different.

Answer (score 0):

you may try like this,

```
$result = explode(',', $data['col2']);
foreach($result as $row){
 $colvalues = $colvalues.$row;
}
```

now you may echo like this,

```
<input type="text" name="col2"  value="<?php echo $colvalues; ?>"/>
```

Comment: i put your code like this...but this display only one values in textbox not all  ..<?php  
  $data = 0;
  if(isset($_GET['edit']))
  {
  $col1= $_GET['edit'];
  $data = $database->getRow("SELECT * FROM master where col1= :col1",array(':col1'=>$col1));
  $result = explode(',', $data['col2']);
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $colvalues = $colvalues.$row;
 }
  }   
?>  <input type="text" name="col2" id="coupon" style="width:300px;" value="<?php echo $colvalues; ?>" class="field" />

Comment: check,  print_r($data['col2']) is it has one array index or more?